# error in spliting equation in two lines

Tags: math-mode, equations, split

I have tried writting this in one equation

[image: equation]

So I have tried the folowing :

```
      \begin{equation}
      \begin{split}
      \phi^{(1)}(x,y,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\frac{\gamma +\coth(\xi h_2)}{Q(\xi)} e^{\xi(y+h_1)}\left[\frac{\omega_1^2 \cos(\omega_1(t-\\tau))-\omega_2^2 \cos(\omega_2(t-\\tau))}{\omega_1^2 - \omega_2^2} \widetilde{P_0}(\xi,t)\right]e^{-\xi x} \ d\xi \\
      &+ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\frac{g \epsilon \xi}{Q(\xi)} e^{\xi(y+h_1)}\left[\frac{ \cos(\omega_2(t-\\tau))-\cos(\omega_1(t-\\tau))}{\omega_1^2 - \omega_2^2}  \widetilde{P_0}(\xi,t)\right]e^{-\xi x} \ d\xi
      \end{split}
      \end{equation}
```

but I end up with errors

`.! Missing } inserted.<inserted text>} \end{split}`

Comment: You've got a bunch of `\\tau` which should be only `\tau`.

Comment: And you need an additional alignment tab `&` before the `=` sign to achieve your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\\tau` doesn't work so well.  This does:

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}


 \begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
      \begin{split}
      \phi^{(1)}(x,y,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\frac{\gamma +\coth(\xi h_2)}{Q(\xi)} e^{\xi(y+h_1)}\biggl[\frac{\omega_1^2 \cos(\omega_1(t-\tau))-         \omega_2^2 \cos(\omega_2(t-\tau))}{\omega_1^2 - \omega_2^2} \widetilde{P_0}(\xi,t)\biggr]e^{-\xi x} \ d\xi 
        \\
  + 
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\frac{g \epsilon \xi}{Q(\xi)} e^{\xi(y+h_1)}\left[\frac{ \cos(\omega_2(t-\tau))-\cos(\omega_1(t-\tau))}{\omega_1^2 - \omega_2^2}  \widetilde{P_0}(\xi,t)\right]e^{-\xi x} \ d\xi
      \end{split}
      \end{equation}

\end{document}
```